# How can i get a coverage report from component tests using Cypress installed on top of CRA with TS?

Tags: typescript, cypress, create-react-app, cypress-component-test-runner

My case is frustratingly specific. Because I couldn't get past my companies login page using e2e tests, I need to rely on `component` tests using Cypress.

I have a working headless Cypress 'component' test working locally and on Jenkins, but I need to figure out how to instrument the code and run Cypress successfully on that code.

I've tried numerous methods that have failed.

My case is very straight forward: use CRA with typescript, install Cypress, use `component` testing, then get a lcov format coverage report.